# How many nonce can resolve block

Tags: block, difficulty, nonce

I'm wonder how many nonce can resolve block in current difficulty? How can be than number counted?

Answer (score 1):

The number of nonces required to be tried is, on average, 4.294 billion multiplied by the difficulty. The current difficulty (February 20, 2016) is 163 billion. So right now, just over 700 quadrillion hashes are required, on average, to mine a block.